# Hiding files/directories from goto menu, but keep in project tree

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is it possible to hide specific files or directories from the "Goto Anything" menu, but still **keep** them in the project's tree?

(my specific issue is: I have files of the same name which get automatically copied to a "dist" directory from a "src" direactory on build. Now it happens, that I accidentally edit a file from the "dist" directory which means that I'm effectively losing all changes)